# Hide spurious messages from console while debugging in Firefox

Tags: firefox, logging, console, firefox-developer-tools

I'm having trouble seeing relevant errors and warnings from my app through a mass of irrelevant messages, including:

- Insecure content warnings (nothing I can do about it right now)
- `Strict-Transport-Security` warnings (no idea, not my area)
- `Error: WebGL warning: texImage2D` apparently generated by a library I'm using, nothing I can do about it.
- `Loading failed for the <script>` - due to ad blocking software I'm using.
- `Content Security Policy: Couldn’t process unknown directive ‘report-to’` no idea, not my area.

I can only find ways to hide all errors, or hide all warnings.

Is there a way to prevent certain messages such as these ever appearing in the log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such feature in the Firefox DevTools yet (as of Firefox 59), unfortunately. I [requested this in bug 1255311](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1255311) some time ago, though.

Also, I just [created another bug report covering several other console filtering feature requests](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1441085).

Comment: Thanks very much for the definitive answer at least.